# Dynamic oracle sql query based on start and end date

Tags: sql, oracle

My table:

[image: Table]

Based on Start and End date, I need to get output something like this:

[image: Output]

Assume start date as 1-sep-2020 and end date as 09-sep-2020 (provided dynamically).
Based on above dates, date should be column name and id should be data under respective column.
If id is not present on respective date, in input table it should be null.

I'm not able to figure out query for this. Please, anyone suggest me in writing the query for above.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT name, dat, id
  FROM tbl
)
PIVOT
(
  max(id)
  FOR dat IN ('01-Sep-2020', '02-Sep-2020', '03-Sep-2020', '04-Sep-2020', '05-Sep-2020', '06-Sep-2020', '07-Sep-2020')
)
ORDER BY name;
```

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=63413c3d5ce0e3a67e9c18d0fe39b21f

Comment: Thanks for the query....What if i have 2 diiferent ids with same name...in that case max() will not work. I need to retrieve both ids..

Comment: I have an alternative suggestion, not sure if you will like it: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3117ff3c76ab50ee67410676c5f3fd8c